# .htaccess ModRewrite: Url was not found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My goal is to redirect `http://ipaddress/directory/file.php?id=47` to `http://ipaddress/directory/47` with .htaccess. The **id** parameter will vary and can be any string of numbers like 1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 300, etc. My current **.htaccess** file is below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /directory/%1? [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite does change the url to what I want! But I get an error after being redirected, which states, **Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server.** I'm not sure why the redirect works but does not load the previous page which had the **id** parameter and actual PHP file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need an internal rewrite for

```sh
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` condition is used to make sure that redirect rule is not executed in the next loop of `mod_rewrite` after rewriting is done from last rules.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples please try following rules. Make sure your htaccess is present in root folder. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Making RewriteEngine ON here.
RewriteEngine on
##Checking condition if THE_REQUEST is in same format which OP has mentioned for URI and mentioning Rule then.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```